# How would I go about implementing platform-agnostic file crawling on the Java 8 Files API?

Tags: java, file

I am looking to use this API to crawl through a configurable list of directories and put their paths in an SQLite database - there are many options here, and I am considering using the walk method.

Would there be a better way to do it? This needs to work for both Linux and Windows.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-

Comment: The walk method works on Linux, Windows and Mac (and VMS and OS/400 too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might look at `Files.walkFileTree()`

with signature `public static Path walkFileTree(Path start, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor) throws IOException`

Extend the `SimpleFileVisitor<T>` class and implement what you want to do there.

As java is platform independent this should work on both OS-es

Comment: I think `Files.walk()` is a nicer method.